# LOAD DATA statement not working in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

When I run the statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/path/date.txt' 
INTO TABLE dimdate
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(date_id, yyyymmdd, fulldate, weekofyear, month, quarter, year);
```

I keep getting the following error messages and I do not know why?

> Error starting at line 1 in command:
>   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Onyafrika/Documents/CS779/data/dim_with_id/date.txt' 
>   Error report:
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 2 in command:
>   INTO TABLE dimdate
>   Error report:
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 3 in command:
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>   Error report:
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 4 in command:
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
>   Error report:
>   Unknown Command

Comment: Oracle 11g R2 is the database. User has DBA privileges.

Comment: How are you running this? It's a sql*loader control file, you can't just run that in a SQL worksheet in SQL Developer. (Might be a menu somewhere to handle it though.)

Comment: There is no `LOAD DATA` statement in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Like others indicated, `LOAD DATA` is not an Oracle Database command.  It's specific to MySQL (or derivatives like MariaDB or Percona Server). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html.  Maybe the confusion since Oracle corp. owns MySQL?

But to solve your actual issue of loading flat file data into Oracle Database 11gR2, look either into SQL*Loader (most similar to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, or possibly use an External Table (similar to `LOAD DATA INFILE`).

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ

http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.php